# Efficient sampling of tournament match-ups for Bradley-Terry modeling

Tags: bradley-terry-model

I am training an AI to learn to play a game through reinforcement learning. The procedure has produced a set of $N$ agents: $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_N$. I wish to estimate a *skill rating* $\beta_i$ for each agent $A_i$, according to the [Bradley-Terry model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model). In the Bradley-Terry model, the probability of agent $A_i$ defeating $A_j$ in a match is given by:

$$
\frac{e^{\beta_i}}{e^{\beta_i} + e^{\beta_j}}
$$

If my compute budget were infinite, I could run a full round-robin tournament, playing $G$ games for each of the $\binom{N}{2}$ possible match-ups, and then estimating each $\beta_i$ by maximizing log likelihood.

However, my compute budget is finite, so I would like to approximate this ideal approach with a smaller number of match-ups. My question is, **what is a principled way to decide which match-ups to run?**

In other words, given a sequence of match-ups I have run thus far, together with their results, how can I decide on a next match-up to run, with the aim of accelerating convergence to the ratings I would have calculated in the ideal approach?

Some relevant details:

- When I run a match-up of $G$ games between two fixed agents, the computational cost is actually sublinear in $G$. This is due to some computational details (the ability to batch neural network inference on a GPU). In other words, we can assume that $G$ is a reasonably large constant, meaning that if we schedule one game between two agents, we can get many more "for free".
- The iterative nature of the reinforcement learning procedure affords me certain *expectations* (but not *guarantees*) about the relative skill levels of the players. I can encode these expectations in an $N\times N$ bool matrix, $M$, where $M[i, j]$ is true if I expect that $\beta_i \leq \beta_j$. The transitive nature of skill in the Bradley-Terry model implies that this matrix can represent the edges of a DAG. I mention this in case this matrix can help with match-up selection.